# Stephen Wolfram Computational Model and the hypergraphs structure

Tags: cosmology, gravity, space, models

[image]I just discovered Stephen Wolfram`s project and model and I am fascinated especially since i had a similar ideea a few years ago without ever reading about it.
I have a question regarding the hypergraphs 2d representation of his model.
I understand that the specific spatial distribution or order does not matter but only the connection and identity of each node is what is important. In the same time i see these graphical representations of the hypergraphs and they look very beautifull and organic. My question is, is there any real physical or mathematical correspondence between the shape of the hypergraphs and the  spatial structure of a potential Universe that they might generate/represent? In other words, is the localization o these nodes rigid, flexible, multidimensional? They look very interesting and meaningfull but are they also an aesthetic interpretation?

Another related question, is the density of these nodes relative, dynamic?
How does the model explain time dilation due to gravitational fields and black hole proximity? Is the gravitational field a function of the density of these nodes?

Thanks !

Comment: You may wish to ask somewhere on Wolfram's own forum https://community.wolfram.com/content?curTag=wolfram%20fundamental%20physics%20project

Comment: I have asked  exactly there and it seems that their forum is much more  specific more like a laboratory and I was strangely redirected here among other places.

Comment: The Wolfram forum told you to ask about Wolfram's theory here? Could I see what they said? It is an odd redirection.

Comment: This is part of their reply : This community group is intended to discuss technical details directly relevant to the Wolfram Fundamental Physics Project. You are welcome to join the conversation on non technical aspects of the project on the announcement blog:
https://writings.stephenwolfram.com/2020/04/finally-we-may-have-a-path-to-the-fundamental-theory-of-physics-and-its-beautiful
Feel free to share your ideas on other physics forums, for instance:
https://physics.stackexchange.com

Comment: I have just simplified my question and posted it again on Wolfram forums. As a side note, I noticed that there is very little interaction over there and only few of the questions/posts do receive a reply. https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2395893